# Re-Using HTML elements across all component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have 3 views (components) dashboard, secondlevel, thirdlevel. I have also Header and Footer views(components) in the page.

Initially the 'dashboard' view will have a icon. When clicking on that, it will show the 'secondlevel' view.

The 'secondlevel' view will have a icon. When clicking on that, it will show the 'thirdlevel' view. I achieved the requirement perfectly with the help of routers.

Now my requirement is to have a 'Previous' button in 'secondlevel' and 'thirdlevel' views to go back to the previous views. When we click the 'previous' button on the 'thirdlevel' view, will show the 'secondlevel' view. In the same way, when we click 'previous' button in the 'secondlevel' will show the 'dashboard' view.

I can achieve this by having the  element in the html of those components. But I don't want to have 'previous' button in all the components ('secondlevel' and 'thirdlevel' html). I also don't want to have the 'previous' button at the header or footer.

I want to keep the  element in only one component and reuse the same in other components.

Do we have any concept of creating the element in one component and reusing the same in another components.? Please guide me the best approach to achieve this.

Comment: Please let me know, if this is fine, else i will explain further.

Comment: Basically you just want to create a component/template and reuse it in other components ? well that's called a template I believe

Comment: It would be great, if you could provide an example.